# VBA RemovingDuplicates

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a macro in Excel which will remove the duplicate values from a range of data. I will use the `.RemoveDuplicates` method. The issue i have come across is i need to remove duplicate values based on other columns.

An Example of the Excel Sheet: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qULPf.png

The image linked above needs to turn into : https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDHON.png

So as can be seen, i need to keep some duplicate values if its corresponding Interface ID is different. Is there any way in i can store both Point Source and Interface ID into a Tuple style collection and then use the `.RemoveDuplicates` on that collection to obtain the results of the second link? Or am i looking over another form of solution?

Sorry, i am very new to VBA.

Answer (score 0):

You can still achieve what you want using the `RemoveDuplicates` method. So in your case it will be

```
.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlNo
```

Answer (score 0):

> i need to keep some duplicate values if its corresponding Interface ID is different

yes, this is possible, but could you please clarify:

your attached snapshots shows results before removing duplicates and after

[image]

but based on your requirements must be like this

[image]

So question is, what exactly you want, what shows in your attached pictures or what described in requirements?